# Launch new Chrome process with new different processes

Tags: google-chrome

If chrome.exe is launched, the usual behavior is for that new window and tab to join the same "instance" of Chrome running in the background. Specifically, they all share a networking and audio utility processes.

I would like to run a new instance of Chrome on Windows, that has its own separate set of utility processes. In other words, if you open the Chrome Task Manager, I shouldn't see tabs and processes from another instance.

Chromium flag --single-process is buggy and unsupported on Chrome, so that doesn't solve it, and I also don't strictly need a single process, just a separate set of processes.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  This might not be the only approach, or the best one.  Also, this is an application usage question so you might get better answers at SuperUser.com

Comment: @DaveS I'm listening to audio coming from the chrome mixer. The problem is that there's only one audio output, all tabs are mixed together. Having separate mixer processes would solve this.

Comment: @DaveS Also, I'm not just listening to audio coming from Chrome.. I'm listening to audio from many processes. Therefore I would like to avoid special-casing Chrome if possible, and separating mixer instances seems like the best solution if it's possible.

Comment: Makes sense.  If you only need 2 could you use a second Chromium-based browser instead of a second Google Chrome?

Comment: @DaveS It's not just 2

Comment: You could try the Chromium Embedded Framework, each instance runs its own separate set of processes there is no hidden master process  - http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html